# Error when I running Vagrant up or vagrant up --provision MacOS

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, vvv-wordpress, vvvv

Vagrant 2.3.4
macOS Catalina 10.15.7
VirtualBox Version 7.0.8

I'm using vagrant and [VVV](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/) to setup WordPress & [Sage](https://roots.io/sage/). I have installed VirtualBox and Vagrant.
When I run "vagrant up" I have this error :

```
==> default: Trigger run failed
==> default: An error occurred in the underlying SSH library that Vagrant uses.
==> default: The error message is shown below. In many cases, errors from this
==> default: library are caused by ssh-agent issues. Try disabling your SSH
==> default: agent or removing some keys and try again.
==> default:
==> default: If the problem persists, please report a bug to the net-ssh project.
==> default:
==> default: timeout during server version negotiating
```

When I run "vagrant up --provision" I have this error :

```
==> default: [vagrant-goodhosts] Checking for host entries
==> default: [vagrant-goodhosts] Finished processing
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
```

I remove & reinstall VirtualBox & Vagrant so it's maybe a problem of versions...

Thanks a lot

I remove & reinstall VirtualBox & Vagrant